# How do I send an error to the constructor of the Exception class in addition to string?

Tags: c#

I am trying send exceptions to the base constructor but I don't know how to send it.
Should I need create an exception?
Here the code of the class:

```
public class InvalidEntityException : Exception
{
    public InvalidEntityException(string message, Exception ex) : base(message, ex) { }
}
```

The exception look like this:

> throw new InvalidEntityException( "Add function :: DAL", ???????);

How do I need throw the exceptions?

Comment: Are you inside a catch clause? Please show more context

Comment: Maybe it's okay?
throw new DuplicateIdException( "Add function :: DAL_ORDER", new Exception());
????

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside a `catch` clause or have a current exception object available otherwise, use that exception object.

```
try
{
    // code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new InvalidEntityException("Add function :: DAL", ex);
}
```

If you don't have a current exception object, just pass `null`.

```
throw new InvalidEntityException("Add function :: DAL", null);
```

---

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.-ctor) of the `Exception` class constructor:

> `public Exception (string? message, Exception? innerException);`
>
> `innerException` Exception
>
> The exception that is the cause of the current exception, or a null
> reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if no inner exception is
> specified.

Comment: And if you are never going to pass in an exception, change the constructor to call `base(message, null)`